# Openshift deployment is not doing what is in my local .gitignore file

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift

I've got a line in my local .gitignore file to ignore a directory /user. I just don't want this directory to be changed in any way on the remote hosting version. People are using it to store files...

But when I push to openshift it deletes everything in that directory, instead of ignoring it. There is a mismatch now going on between git local and got remote. How can I reset what openshift is working form? Why are new files in that directory on the server being deleted, when I git push. I checked both the version of .gitignore on the local machine and on Openshift remote and they are the same. So it should ignore that directory. Damn it...

Answer (score 1):

For persistent data storage, you should be using the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` directory. Check the [Directory Environment Variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#directory-variables) section at developers.openshift.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jiri Fiala. But now how do I easily convert my Rails app to use OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR instead of the current /user directory?

Comment: You will need to read the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` environment variable and use it in your application on appropriate places where you access `/user` directory. You can check an example on accessing the env. variable [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#reading-variable-examples).

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to do it  with the \public\users without the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR business... I'll  just use SFTP to bypass Git. Because people have to be able to browser to domainxyz.com/users/usr1/ And I don't see how that will work with the Openshift variable.